# X-Frame-Options and Strict-Transport-Security are prohbiting me from uploading any images via ajax error due to self signed cert (on a dev box)

Tags: ajax, files

When trying to upload an image in a Node Edit form, I'm getting an Ajax error in the main browser window. The browser console is displaying complaints surrounding Strict Transport and X-Frame options.

> Strict-Transport-Security: The connection to the site is
>   untrustworthy, so the specified header was ignored.[Learn More]
>   form-VHZcgnXwba2plRQ9nE0JQPqgblsvmrgYHtOtCywfYmo

And

> Load denied by
>   X-Frame-Options:
>   https://server.ext/file/ajax/field_module_images/und/0/form-VHZcgnXwba2plRQ9nE0JQPqgblsvmrgYHtOtCywfYmo
>   does not permit framing

**We're I'm at now:**
I've followed guildlines in [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924). I've not run into this issue with other sites. The only difference in this site and others we run is that this is our first on RHEL 7.  I've read other reports about playing with jQuery Update with little luck.

**Potential issue:**
Could this be because I'm on a dev server with a self signed certificate?

What I've tried:

I've tried adding the follwing inside /etc/httpd/conf.d/Xframe.conf

```
<Location /var/www/html>
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</Location>
```

This seems to have had to impact after a service restart.

Comment: Looks like the header you've set is being ignored because your certificate is invalid, and the browser can't trust the source. Google "how to trust self signed certificate on [OS here]" and you should be able to continue

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Changing jQuery versions in the admin theme solved that image issue. Though console still shows the Strict transport. This should be resolved as the production servers have a proper certificate. Comment up-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File under just being a bad morning.

It turned out to be the ADMIN THEME was using jQuery 1.4 instead of an updated version. Using jQuery Update, the admin theme now has a 1.8 and content creators are happy.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using a module called ["Security Kit"](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit). If you are, check the admin settings. There is a manual setting for the X-Frame-Options header: /admin/config/system/seckit